# Generating a Maven Java Project with Updated JUnit dependency and Targeting Java 8?

Tags: java, maven

If we generate a maven project like this:

```
 mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=start -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

It generates one targeting `junit 3.8.1` and does not include java 8 at the compiler target.  Is there an archetype that targets a more recent 5+ junit dependency, as well as a compatible test case, and java8?

Comment: It is easy to upgrade to 4.12.  JUnit 5 requires more work.

Comment: Yeah I was considering just creating a github repository and just cloning that as a starting point if there are no archetypes that satisfy this requirement.  I was also considering building a quick archetype generator in Node that would be similar to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/cli since this would allow faster refactoring and updating of the generators I would think ...

Comment: Perhaps add some Angular like class generation features for Java as well to create a more Node like development experience ...

Comment: Just get the junit5 dependency section from the homepage and fix the pom.    Sounds like you are overthinking this.

Comment: I do overthink a lot :)  - It would be nice if Java finally starts moving into a lightweight IDE vscode with lightweight Angular like component generation and layout features though ... have not touched Java in a while and with node the setup for a quick prototyping environment is like 30 seconds whereas with Java it's still ...

Comment: Quick prototyping happens in other languages.  I can recommend using IntelliJ - they help a lot with the tedious work which cannot be avoided in Java.   By the way if you have node.js, then why even bother with Java?

Comment: Long story - For example we have bootstrap but I'm still writing my own CSS framework: https://github.com/superflycss/superflycss .... and you can do things like this with it: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/prototyping-with-bootstrap-4-using-the-superflycss-cli-a40ec24237c2

Comment: I like IntelliJ though - Especially with Kotlin ...

Comment: Writing your own frameworks instead of using what others do, may not be a good idea as others cannot maintain them.  Your boss know of this?

Comment: Well - I'm the boss - So yes the boss knows :)

Comment: Ok, it is very simple to create a new archetype.  The most tricky part is getting the variable substitutions right.

Comment: Yes I have created them in the past ... was just a little shocked at the state of the default project ... and that there is no built in support yet for the most likely use case, which seems to be JUnit 5+ and Java 8 ... At least @Thiago has our back :)

Comment: Somebody has to do it, and you need the newest artifacts of everything anyway.

Comment: Yes that why I mentioned a node based project generator.  I think it's much easier to maintain, update, and add features via node template generators than it is to create archetypes ... archetypes are not bad, but the overall process is really cumbersome compared to what we can do with node and NPM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find one [here](https://github.com/thiagoprocaci/java8-junit5-archetype).

However, you need to install it locally and then generate your application.

Comment: The provided link has not been updated in 5 years.